# How can I convert an MS Access database (.mdb) file to a Sqlite database (.db) file?

Tags: database, sqlite

Can anybody help me convert an MS Access (`.mdb`) file to an Sqlite database (`.db`) file?

I need to convert all the tables and dump the data inside.

Are there any tools available, or is there any API which converts .mdb to .db?

Comment: Do you only need the data or also the Indexes/Constraints (if any) ?
Will this be a 1 time operation ?

Comment: How did you end up converting the database?

Comment: I've answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53687790/752843) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried these 2 tools ? (searched Google for "mdb sqlite")

- [mdb-sqlite](http://code.google.com/p/mdb-sqlite/)
- [access2sqlite](http://code.google.com/p/access2sqlite/)

Comment: Both dead projects?

Comment: https://github.com/arturasn/mdb2sqlite